# Pyinstaller comes with errors when importing backtesting.py module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, back-testing

I am using Windows 11 for Python code development. I have a large Python program that uses the backteting.py module. The program works fine when running it using Visual Studio Code or executing it in the console. However, when I create an EXE file using the Pyinstaller, the EXE file does not work. I managed to reduce the code to two instructions (see below) and yet the EXE program does not work.

```
import backtesting
print ("Hello")
```

I am getting the following warnings when I run the Pyinstaller.

```
115289 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
115301 WARNING: Library msvcrt required via ctypes not found
```

In addition, I am also getting the following errors when I run the EXE file.

```
C:\Users\menb\Documents\tests\test3\test3>test3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "backtesting\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "backtesting\backtesting.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "backtesting\_plotting.py", line 43, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\menb\\Documents\\tests\\test3\\test3\\backtesting\\autoscale_cb.js'
[33336] Failed to execute script 'test3' due to unhandled exception!
```

Any help to solve this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the documentation for `backtesting`.  If a module requires a non-Python file (that's Javascript), then you have to tell Pyinstaller about that separately.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Initially I decided to find why I am getting the two warnings when I run the Pyinstaller.

Comment: I found that one of my folders was not in the PATH. After adding this folder to the PATH, the two warnings are not shoving anymore. That said, the other errors when I run the EXE file, did not go away.

Comment: Right, because your executable is not grabbing a copy of `autoscale_cb.js` unless you tell it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully compile and run the two lines from your example using pyinstaller.

```
import backtesting
print ("Hello")
```

Steps to reproduce.

1. create a new virtual enviornment and install pyinstaller and backtesting
2. create `main.py` with your example code.
3. run
   `pyinstaller -F --collect-all backtesting main.py`

or

4. `pyinstaller -F --collect-all backtesting --collect-all bokeh --collect-all xyzservices main.py`

then run: `dist/main.exe`

OUTPUT:

```
Hello
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your suggestions. I did not create  a new virtual environment yet for some reason and run your suggestions. I got many errors and therefore as a starter I changed

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your suggestions. I did not create  a new virtual environment yet for some reasons and run your suggestions. I got many errors and therefore as a starter I removed from your command the --collect-all bokeh --collect-all xyzservices.

I run the pyinstaller again and it worked fine. Now I will go to my larger program and see if it works too. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: interesting... I tried it without the bokeh and xyzservices and it gave me a bunch of errors.  Glad you got it to work though.  I updated my answer to the solution that worked for you.

Comment: I run the pyinstaller with my larger program and it works also fine. Thank you again for your help.